# how do i generate an apk file in vscode

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-code, android-ndk

i am currently trying to generate an apk file in vscode using the programing language c++
and i am wondering how i could do it.

i have looked up for a compiler and a way to generate it.

Comment: "i have looked up for a compiler and a way to generate it" - an apk file is a package, the compiler has *nothing* to do with generating it. Actually, it's really just a (special) zip file - you could generate it by hand if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

To get the apk file of our flutter project with VS Code, go to the terminal.

flutter build apk

We just have to write.

Our apk file is in the folder where our project is;

build / app / outputs / apk / release

will be in position.

Comment: i would like to know how to create an .apk file from my .cpp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).